# how to remove a second AMPERSAND in a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

1.how to remove second AMPERSAND from following string?
"apple&banana&grape&apple"

2.how to split the string at second AMPERSAND for following string? I want to ignore the first AMPERSAND and split from second AMPERSAND onwards.
"apple&banana&grape&apple"

Comment: I guess you could split it at every ampersand, then join the first and second, and third and fourth elements of the resulting array back together again with ampersands.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = "apple&banana&grape&apple".split('&')
#arr = ["apple", "banana", "grape", "apple"]
```

To solve first query,

```
arr[0..1].join('&').concat(arr[2..-1].join('&'))
# "apple&bananagrape&apple"
```

For second query,

```
[words[0..1].join('&'), words[2..-1]].flatten
#["apple&banana", "grape", "apple"]
```

Comment: Deleted my answer to try and optimise and I see you've updated to the same as my code for the second query :) Actually thought you had it right first time using `rest`... do you not think your original better answers the second query @pramod? Perhaps @harsha can clarify?

Comment: @srack I was about to modify to give more general answer. Suppose, if we want to split from third `&`, then with my original answer we would have three variables.So, modified the solution to answer @harsha-vardhan-reddy second query.

Comment: That's why I went back to the drawing board - got a feeling my current answer doesn't answer the second query correctly, and that yours (in its current state) does! Should find out soon :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a block:

For your first case:

```
 index_to_remove = 2 
 current_index = 0
 my_string = "apple&banana&grape&apple"
 my_string.gsub('&') { |x| current_index += 1; current_index == index_to_remove ? '' : x} 
#=> "apple&bananagrape&apple"
```

For your second case, you can replace the second & with a unique value and split on that:

```
index_to_split = 2 
current_index = 0
my_string = "apple&banana&grape&apple"
my_string.gsub!('&') { |x| current_index += 1; current_index == index_to_split ? '&&' : x}
my_string.split('&&')
#=> ["apple&banana", "grape&apple"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you split the string by the `&`, it's quite simple to rejoin the first two / last two and convert back into a string or array:

```
words = "apple&banana&grape&apple".split('&')

# First query
words[0..1].join('&') + words[2..-1].join('&')
# Giving you: "apple&bananagrape&apple"

# Second query
[words[0..1].join('&'), words[2..-1].join('&')]
# Giving you: ["apple&banana", "grape&apple"]
```

You could tweak this for different length strings and separators as needed.

I imagine there's a good solution using regex matchers, but I'm not too hot on them, so hope this helps in some way!

Comment: read the second query carefully. I think he wants to ignore first `&` and split from second onwards :)

Comment: That was my thinking and why I cleared the answer! Noticed everyone else had gone with this solution so thought I'd pop it back in, and that you'd edited yours to do the same. Think now you've turned it back you have the right solution. +1 to yours...